# Any idea what plant this is?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs, tropical

Have tried multiple apps but still can't get a solid answer. Live in Oahu. Looks like it was damaged earlier due to a lapse in care from a previous owner. Thank you in advance for any help. [image]

Comment: Your picture of the flower is a bit fuzzy. Could you post a better one please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd move it to a shadier spot. They are native to temporate forests, not the tropical sun.

Answer (score 2):

Rhododendron (prob. obtusum
Found in much USA. Not native to Hawaii, best disposed of. replaced with Native vegetation.

[image]